# Valid Analytics.MaxAcceptedClockDeviation values

Tags: xconnect

I am trying to increase the `Analytics.MaxAcceptedClockDeviation` to a large number, but keep getting:

> 3876 23:11:29 WARN  The "Analytics.MaxAcceptedClockDeviation" setting contains an invalid value. The default value is used instead. Invalid value: "0.24:00:00". Default value: "00:00:10"

The default configuration value is:

```
<setting name="Analytics.MaxAcceptedClockDeviation" value="0.00:00:10" patch:source="Sitecore.Xdb.config"/>
```

What is valid format for this setting? For example for setting it to 24 hours?

Answer (score 4):

`TimeSpan` settings in Sitecore use `DateUtil.ParseTimeSpan` method internally

Following metadata of that method: *Format must be 00:00:00 representing hours, minutes and seconds. A fourth optional part may be added, representing milliseconds (ie. 00:00:00:00)*

You are using "." in the value, which is not correct.(Sitecore don't expect usage of dot character in this type of settings at all). Remove "0." from your setting and I suppose it will start to work.

Comment: The following example values seem to work `1.00:00:00` and `24:00:00`. Indeed not recommended values for production, but my dev setup has some problems.